# putting the output from exec() into a pipe

Tags: c, pipe

I'm having some trouble with a bit of piping. I'm creating a shell and I am in the process of expanding command line parameters. 
I think I need to use `dup2`, but I've been having trouble implementing it to the point that I just reset all my code to what I had the day before because of how broken it ended up being. Right now I have two functions that interact with each other. One makes a string, and the other calls `exec`, and I need to grab that output and put it into the string in the other function using a pipe.

I have a function called `expand`:

```
...
new = "my username is ";
string = "echo Lazarus";

//make the pipe
int myPipe[2];
pipe(myPipe);
int n;
char buffer[65000];

//call changeString         
changeString(string, myPipe[0], myPipe[1]);

/*currently, this is how I can get a string into the pipe. 
I need to do this in changeString instead.*/
write(myPipe[1], "this is a test", 14); 

//read from the pipe in a loop until EOF
int stillReading = 1;
while(stillReading != 0){
   if((n = read(myPipe[0], buffer, 65000)) >= 0){   
      stillReading = 0;
      buffer[n] = '\0';
   }    
}

close(myPipe[0]);
...

//add the result to the new string
for(int i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++){
   string[stringIndex++] = buffer[i];
}

printf("string is now '%s'\n", string); //should output: 'my username is Lazarus'
...
```

And then I have a process `changeString`:

```
...

cpid = fork();
if(cpid < 0){
   return -1;
}

if(cpid == 0){
   //We are the child!

   //where argList[0] == the first word of string, and argList = string
   //(this works just fine)
   execvp(argList[0], argList);

...

...
```

What I need to do is put some code into changeString (dup2?) that allows me to put the output from exec into the new string. So that at the end, I get `new` being "my username is Lazarus"

Comment: immediately after: `execvp(argList[0], argList);` should be: `perror( "execvp failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE );  then there needs to be a `} else { ` (the 'else' related to: `if(cpid ==0)`) waitpid( cpid, &status ); followed by any code you might want to use to look at the `status`.

Comment: what is the contents of the array `arglist[]`?

Comment: after the code executed: `close(myPipe[0]);` no one will be able to `read()` from `myPipe[0]`

Comment: @user3629249 in this case arglist contains the string "echo Lazarus" (arglist is an array of strings, so it really contains "echo" and "Lazarus"). That string gets executed by the exec function, then I need to take what stdout is given ("Lazarus") and I need to pipe it back into `expand`.

Comment: regarding this comment: `read from the pipe in a loop until EOF` and following block of code:  using the `read()` function to read from the pipe, a EOF will never be seen, rather a byte count of 0 will be returned from`read()`

Comment: regarding: `string = "echo Lazarus";`,  How is `string` defined.  (I suspect it is defined as `char *string = NULL;`   the character string: `echo Lazarus` will be located in readonly memory, so cannot added to, changed, etc.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce your problem and therefore be able to give you good suggestions.

Comment: Regarding your comment about the contents of `arglist[]`  The last entry always needs to be NULL.  The first entry, you say is `echo`  Well, that will not execute on its' own.  The first entry needs to be (in linux) something like `/bin/bash` and the second entry needs to be something like `-c` and both pipes need to be open when calling `execvp()`

Comment: @user3629249 I'm working on creating a shell, and this is part of that. I should have mentioned that for sure (I've updated the question). The exec part works great. What's happening here is:  `1) I find something that looks like $(echo hello)` > `2) I extract "echo hello" from that and send it to changeString` > `3) in changestring, I call exec on that, which gives an output in the terminal of "hello"` >>> now step 4 needs to be `pipe that output back into expand so that I can put it into my new string`. A good example is  "echo my directory  is $(pwd)"!  >>  "my directory is /home/....!"